# Cloud Firestore Query filter out fields with a blank string

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Pretty simple, trying to filter out results where a string field is "".  Cant seem to find a way to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Firestore does not provide inequality filters.  You can only filter *for* specific values and ranges of values.

Comment: yeah the inequality doesnt exactly fit for strings and Im already using a range filter so couldnt do what is in that post

Comment: What you're asking **is** about inequality for empty string.  When you say "filter out", that's the same as a filter for inequality.  Firestore only applies filters **for** values. I suggest not allowing an empty string at all, and instead use a boolean to indicate the case you want to filter.  So, you could filter **for** empty=true.